# Is non-differentiable having the derivative a contradiction?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, definition

I'm reading this [book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=34Ic0K3LQxEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 104 they define what means a function being differentiable:

[image]

Afterwards they give the following example:

[image]

Is it not a contradiction? Following the definition $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there is $D_f(a)$. In the example, the derivative $D_f(0,0)$ does exist at $(0,0)$. What am I missing?

Comment: If two or more variables occur, you have to distinguish between the partial derivates (forming the gradient) and the total derivate. The later can be non-existent, although the gradient exists.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your comment. I'm not talking about the partial derivatives and the gradient. The fact is _there exists_ the derivative $D_f(a)$

Comment: The Nabla-symbol usually means the gradient, so $D_f$ should denote the gradient here.

Comment: @Peter so this $D_f$ is not the $D_f$ of the definition?

Comment: Another example for "don't believe everything in the book".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; the final sentence in the second excerpt is simply an error.  The derivative $D_f(0,0)$ does *not* exist, nor does the gradient $\nabla f(0,0)$ (as defined earlier on page 110).  All that is true is that the partial derivatives exist.

Comment: The gradient is simply the vector of the partial derivates, so if the partial derivates exist, the gradient exists as well.

Comment: @Peter: That is not the definition of the gradient in this book.  See page 110 of the link at the start of the question.

Comment: Does that mean that the book defined the gradient wrong ? This would be humiliating ...

Comment: @Peter: No, the definition is fine, it's just that there is no universally accepted definition of "gradient".  The definition in the book is equivalent to your definition as long as the function is differentiable, but the definition in the book only exists when the function is differentiable.

Comment: OK, I understand. I wasn't aware of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the book is right. Even though all the partial derivatives exist, since the function is not continuous at (0,0), the function can't be Frechet differentiable at that point.

Comment: The book claims that the derivative exists, not just that the partial derivatives do. The existence of a derivative contradicts the statement that the function is not differentiable.